# Passing array of class objects to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, object

Passing an array of objects to a function is not giving back the desired values set in the `settingUp` function.

Try to print the values stored in the first item of the array in the main function.

main.ccp:

```
//** Libraries included **//
using namespace std;
//#include "common.h"
#include "settingUp.h"



int main(){

statusClass status[5];

//** Main Functions **//
settingUp(status);

status[1].printValues();
}
```

settings.h:

```
#ifndef settingUp_h
#define settingUp_h

//** Libraries **//
#include "statusClass.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dataClass.h"

void settingUp(statusClass *_status);

#endif
```

settings.ccp //UPDATE: few lines corrected!

```
//** Libraries **//
#include "settingUp.h"



//** Status classes and their functions **//
void settingUp(statusClass *_status){

//statusClass statusProv;

dataClass * prueba0 = new dataClass(); //Corrected!
dataClass * prueba1 = new dataClass(); //Corrected!
dataClass * prueba2 = new dataClass(); //Corrected!

const dataClass * arrayPrueba[3];

prueba0.setValues(1);
prueba1.setValues(2);
prueba2.setValues(3);

arrayPrueba[0] = prueba0; //Corrected!
arrayPrueba[1] = prueba1; //Corrected!
arrayPrueba[2] = prueba2; //Corrected!


_status[1].setValues(1, arrayPrueba);


//_status = &statusProv;

_status[0].printValues();
}
```

UPDATE:

statusClass.cpp:

```
//** Libraries **//
#include "statusClass.h"



//** Status classes and their functions **//
void statusClass::setValues (uint8_t _statusSelectorByte, const dataClass **_array){

    newStatusSelectorByte = _statusSelectorByte;
    array = _array;
};

void statusClass::printValues(){

    printf("TP: statusClass -> printValues: Prueba = %d\n", newStatusSelectorByte);
    printf("TP: statusClass -> printValues: arrayPrueba = %d\n", array[1]->length); 
}
```

`printValues()` in the `settingUp()` gives the right values, not in `main.cpp`.

Update: for array[0]->length works, for array[2]->length does not work.

Comment: As a side note, it's not a good idea to do `using namespace std;`, especially before doing your `#include`. Just use `std::...` where needed.

Comment: `arrayPrueba[0] = &prueba0;` This makes no sense.  `arrayPrueba[0]` is a `dataClass`, but `&prueba0` is a `dataClass*`.  The latter cannot be assigned to the former unless you've overloaded `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
dataClass prueba0;
```

you create an object on the stack. This object is valid until you exit that function.

One solution is to allocate that object:

```
dataClass * prueba0 = new dataClass();
```

That means at some point you'll need to delete the object with:

```
delete prueba0;
```

To avoid having to use `delete`, you should look into using shared pointers.

---

I think your next problem is that in main you have:

```
statusClass status[5];
```

So 5 different `status` objects.

Then inside the initialization function, you specifically initialize `_status[1]`:

```
_status[1].setValues(1, arrayPrueba);
```

In other words, your `_status[0]` access within the initialization is going to show the *random* values that were on the stack when entering `main()` (which by luck are zeroes by default).

Maybe you are thinking that:

```
array = _array;
```

copies the values from one array to another. Right now, all that does is save a pointer. The array on the left is the pointer you created named `arrayPrueba`.

I just don't think you understand your code much and to tell you the truth, you should be using `std::vector` instead of C arrays. If you really want to write C++ code, learn the standard library (STL).

Comment: Something is still missing, it is not possible to access arrayPrueba[1] or arrayPrueba[2] in statusClass from main.cpp.

statusClass.cpp:
~~~
//** Status classes and their functions **//
void statusClass::setValues (uint8_t _statusSelectorByte, const dataClass **_array){

 newStatusSelectorByte = _statusSelectorByte;
 array = _array;
};

void statusClass::printValues(){

 printf("TP: statusClass -> printValues: Prueba = %d\n", newStatusSelectorByte);
 printf("TP: statusClass -> printValues: arrayPrueba = %d\n", array[1]->length); 
}
~~~

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía You don't want to put that much code in a comment. Edit your question and add it there. Then post a comment saying you made an update and what the update is about. You can use backticks (\`) to enter function names like `setValues()`.

Comment: does it  have now a better presentation? help me here once again please. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I made an update.